# Constructibility of $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I would like to show that $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is not a [constructible number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConstructibleNumber.html).

I would like to use the following lemma:

> Let $P(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ a polynomial with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$, if $P$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$ then $P$ has no roots in $K$ (the set of constructible numbers).

How can I judiciously choose $a,b,c$ to achieve this?

Comment: While your lemma is correct, it applies only for algebraic numbers of degree less than or equal to $3$, whereas $\arctan(1/2)$ is transcendental.

Answer (score 3):

From the relation:
$$\arctan\frac{1}{2}=\frac{i}{2}\cdot\log\frac{2-i}{2+i}\tag{1}$$
and the fact that the logarithm of any algebraic number $\alpha\not\in\{0,1\}$ is trascendental (it follows from the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)) we have that $\arctan\frac{1}{2}$ is not even algebraic, so it is not constructible for sure.